# how to call member function from map of classes

Tags: c++, stdmap, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to call member function through a map of member function ptr
that is a data member of a different class

```
{    
    class B
    {
    public:
    typedef void (B::*funcp)(int);
    B()
    {
        func.insert(make_pair("run",&B::run));
    }
        void run(int f);
        map<string,funcp>func;
    };

    class A
    {
        public:
        A();
        void subscribe(B* b)
        {
            myMap["b"] = b;
        }
        map<string,B*>myMap;
        void doSome()
        {
             myMap["place"]->func["run"](5);
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        A a;
        B b;
        a.subscribe(&b);
        a.doSome();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but im getting

> error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in
>   ‘((A*)this)->A::myMap.std::map,
>   B*>::operator[](std::basic_string(((const char*)"place"),
>   std::allocator()))->B::func.std::map, void
>   (B::*)(int)>::operator[](std::basic_string(((const char*)"run"),
>   std::allocator())) (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->*
>   ((A*)this)->A::myMap.std::map,
>   B*>::operator[](std::basic_string(((const char*)"place"),
>   std::allocator()))->B::func.std::map, void
>   (B::*)(int)>::operator[](std::basic_string(((const char*)"run"),
>   std::allocator()))) (...)’

i also tryed :

```
{
    auto p = myMap["place"];
    (p->*func["run"])(5);
}
```

and thien the error it:

> ‘func’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: I suggest you learn about [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (or possibly [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)), as that will make stuff like this *much* easier.

Comment: `->*` is not like `->`– the thing on the right is not the name of a member but an expression that is evaluated in the current scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B* bptr = myMap["place"];
(bptr->*(bptr->func["run"]))(5);
```

OK tested now, and thanks to Sombrero Chicken for fixing the typos. You don't need all those parens, but it's probably a good idea to leave them in.

The thing you are missing is that you need your `B` pointer twice. Once to find the map in the other object, and once to call the member function using the member function pointer.

Comment: tnx you very much, in me real code i used shared_ptr so i need to change little bit: {auto p = myMap["place"].get(); (p->*(p->func["run"]))(5);}

Answer (score 3):

In the code you've tried, `p` is of type `B*`. In order to access its `run` method pointer you should write `p->func["run"]` not `p->*func["run"]`, and finally to invoke that method you should write `p->*(p->func["run"])`.

```
void doSome() {
    // pointer to the B object
    B* p = myMap["place"];

    // pointer to the method
    B::funcp method_ptr = p->func["run"];

    // invoke the method on the object
    p->*method_ptr(5);
}
```